# How to find the earliest integer cartesian cordinates point in the all positive quadrant given a degree in polar cordinate?

Tags: coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates

If I have been given a degree in the polar coordinate, how do I find the earliest point having the same degree and whose x and y coordinates are integers and not fractional in the cartesian plane?

Comment: So are you asking: Given $\alpha$, when is $\tan{\alpha}$ rational?

Comment: Well the gradient of the line formed is $\tan{\theta}$, which is sometimes irrational. $\frac{y}{x}$ is always rational so sometimes there does not exist $x,y$ where $x$ and $y$ are both integers that lie on a certain line.

Comment: @Landuros or is there a way to get a point which a near to integer values, with a difference of say < 10^-6, like 11.00000016 instead of 11?

Comment: @user3243499 Yes, there is always a way to get to a point that has a difference of $10^{-6}$.

Comment: @Landuros Please describe the strategy that you are suggesting. Maybe as an answer. thanks.